# Get only future days with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I'm trying to create a list of *N* elements of dates (moment.js objects) of the given days (e.g `['Friday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday']`).
I want to start always from today and list the future *N* dates but the problem is that it also includes the past if possible. The question is how to solve it elegantly? I think I could add some conditions to fix it but maybe there's proper "moment.js"-ish way.

An example will describe it better:

```
let initialPoint = moment();
const weekDays = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'];
let days = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  days.push(moment(initialPoint).day(weekDays[i]));
}

days.forEach(day => console.log(day.format()));
```

Today in my case is **27.08.2019** but it also includes 25 and 26.

The result of the code:

```
2019-08-27T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-28T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-29T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-30T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-31T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-25T12:31:55+02:00
2019-08-26T12:31:55+02:00
```

The code in action is here https://jsfiddle.net/423zoeaw/4/

**Note 1:** Don't care about sorting of the days.

**Note 2:** The example doesn't make much sense but it reproduces the bug I have in the real app.

Comment: did you want it should be a swap  for the first element and Tuesday and go to the third element in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method built into MomentJS:

```js
// set initial date
// e.g., for Wed 8/28, use moment("8/28/2019")
// for this example, we'll just use today as the starting date
let initialPoint = moment();

// how many days ahead you want to look
let numDays = 7;

// the days you want to include
let weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];

// an array to hold the dates
let days = [];

// Add starting day to the days array
days.push(initialPoint.format());

for (let i = 1; i < numDays; i++) {
  let d = initialPoint.clone().add(i, "days");
  // check if the day is in the array
  if (weekdays.includes(d.format("dddd"))) {
    // Add each subsequent day to the days array
    days.push(d);
  }
}

console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you only want the name of the day, you can use `.format("dddd")`.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. It lists only 02.09 7 times

Comment: Those were MomentJS objects. It sounds like you want the date string. I modified the answer above to call `format()` to give the date string instead.

Comment: Looks better, but I also need only preselected days `const weekDays = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'];` in my example. It can contain less than 7 days. So to skip dates which are not in the `weekDays` array.

Comment: Also a question about `format()`. I think I don't need it now. I want to work with moment objects, I will need some format at the end in the template

Comment: @igor_c I modified the answer to check if the weekday is in the weekdays array. If it is, it gets added. If not, it skips it.

Comment: @igor_c Also MomentJS objects get added to the array instead of date strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

`days.push(moment(initialPoint).day(weekDays[i]));`

by `days.push(moment().add(i, "days").day(weekDays[i]));`

in `for` loop.

Working fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/423zoeaw/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(){
const weekDays = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
const weekFinl=weekDays.map(day=>day.substring(0, 3));
var dayName = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0];
let days = [];

for(let i = 0; i < weekFinl.length-1; i++) {
if(dayName ===weekFinl[i]){
 days.push(weekFinl[i+1]);
  dayName=weekFinl[i+1];
}

}
console.log(days);
}
add();
```

is that you need without moment

Comment: I think the OP wants to use Moment. In the comments to my answer, OP says: *I want to work with moment objects, I will need some format at the end in the template*